# "Move slower" vs. "move less"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs, comparatives

What is the proper word to fill the blank?

> The more cars there are on a given road, the *_*_ the traffic will move.

The answer is *slower*. But I wonder whether *less* is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, less is incorrect. Less and slower are not synonymous.

Comment: @mattacular Not being synonymous is no reason for either to be incorrect.

Comment: Make your question clearer by stating that you want to know the grammatical error in using *less* in the example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **less** is incorrect because it's not a word that is normally used to describe the movement of cars being driven in traffic. Such cars **move** *slowly* or *quickly*, *slow* or *fast*, and *forward* or *backward*. I suppose we'd say that one car was moving more or less than another only in an earthquake, when it's not moving under its own power.

Comment: "And if this happens, then the result will be that even less traffic will move than might be carried. "- books.google.com/books?id=gv88AAAAMAAJ

Answer (score 0):

Both would be grammatical, but only *slower* would be logical. Because if you have more cars, then the traffic will be slow not less.

Comment: But the traffic would also move less. Less movement.

Comment: @deadly: that would not be the case.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate that point. In your answer you don't address the fact that it is the *movement* that is being compared, not the traffic directly.

Comment: ''The more cars there are on a given road, the ( ) the traffic will move.'' This is an interesting construction; -_the more_ is surely a quantifier but a comparative adverb is required to replace the placeholder. 'The bigger they come, the harder they fall' 'balances' comparative adjective with comparative adverb. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

*Slower* would be perhaps be the more usual choice, but it depends on the context of the sentence and the intent of the author.

However, either *slower* or *less* would work grammatically.

As Andrew Leach says, a comparative is required, which *slower* and *less* both are.